# Material-UI: Property 'X' does not exist on type '{}' when passing props to makestyles in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am now trying to use Adapting based on props https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    // style rule
    foo: props => ({
        (Error!)
        backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
    }),
    bar: {
        // CSS property(Error!)
        color: props => props.color,
    },
});

function MyComponent() {
    // Simulated props for the purpose of the example
    const props = { backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white' };
    // Pass the props as the first argument of useStyles()
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    return <div className={`${classes.foo} ${classes.bar}`} />
}
export default MyComponent;
```

but I got the error **TS2339: Property 'X' does not exist on type '{}' when passing props**

so what happened here? how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Does the code actually work despite the errors? Do you receive the same notification for props.color? Are you using Typescript, and if so have you tried defining types for the props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second generic argument of `makeStyles` is the props type, [by default is `{}`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1c09e678aeaf951f4748ad06361ffe200dc3534a/packages/material-ui/src/styles/makeStyles.d.ts#L8). You can override it like this:

```
import { DefaultTheme } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles<DefaultTheme, Props>(...)
```

Full working code:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { DefaultTheme } from '@material-ui/styles';

interface Props {
  color: 'red' | 'blue';
}

// you only need to set the type of props once here
const useStyles = makeStyles<DefaultTheme, Props>({
  root: {
    // props now has Props type
    background: (props) =>
      props.color === 'red'
        ? 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)'
        : 'linear-gradient(45deg, #2196F3 30%, #21CBF3 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    // so is this props
    boxShadow: (props) =>
      props.color === 'red'
        ? '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)'
        : '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(33, 203, 243, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    margin: 8,
  },
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67275984/ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-when-passing-props-to-makestyle]

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error because you are using typescript. So if you want fix, you need to define an interface/type:

```
interface PropsStyle {
  backgroundColor: string;
  color: string;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  // style rule
  foo: (props: PropsStyle) => ({
    backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
  }),
  bar: {
    color: (props: PropsStyle) => props.color,
  },
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that you need to declare the props type every time you define the callback. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67280358/9449426) answer if you want to set it once.